# register_rest_route - post or get?

Tags: wordpress, callback, postman, endpoint, wordpress-rest-api

I’m building a WordPress -shop that involves API connection, for the first time.
So far I’m using our API providers test environment creating orders and this is working fine.
However the one thing that is not active in test environment is Callback function which will execute when order has left production and is shipped.

I have created an endpoint for this with a function that will update orderstatus at our site and also send me an email, using register_rest_route.
I also tested this endpoint from Postman using POST method with some json -data in the body and this worked fine.

The ”Create order” is a POST -call which holds the callback url -field in json format in the request body schema.

In the documentation from our API provider there are 2 different GET calls available:

Order status - Retrives status of order

Callback - Execute callback for given order [Internal use only]

If I execute either if these, I get the same results which I assume will be what the callback -function will receive at ”Create Order”?
...so this is what I prepared for in the function which is at my endpoint.

Now to my question, I would like to simulate the callback as close as possible before switching to production environment.
But I’m little confused whether I’m on the right track or not posting to endpoint like this from Postman?
Should my  register_rest_route -enpoint use method ’POST’ or ’GET’ ?

I hope it makes sense, grateful for any help/insight!

Thanks!